# Can anyone recommend solution to my situation with XML

Tags: xml, perl, configuration-files

Sorry for not being clear.
The problem I am trying to convey is that [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) does not allow me direct access to the hash, I must refer to the key in question through the [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) module. Using something like `$xml->{key}`.

Here is the code I am using and a copy of the hash output.

The reason this is a problem is because I need to construct a series of loops using the keys of the hash [seen below], and I cannot build a foreach loop with a hash referrence, when I tried it, perl gave me an error.

So what I am looking for is a module or solution to allow me to dump the contents of the XML file to a hash that I declare in my script. I also need the ability to write back out to an XML file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

system ("clear");

my $xml = XML::Simple->new;

# Using the XML::Simple object, read guest_os.xml to a hash

my $xml_file = $xml->XMLin('config.xml',

                SearchPath => './config',

                SuppressEmpty => 1);




$VAR1 = \{
        'esxi01' => {
                    'password' => 'myspoonistoobig!',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'port' => '22'
                  },
        'esxi02' => {
                    'password' => 'myspoonistoobig!',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'port' => '22'
                  },
        'Setup' => 'FALSE'
      };
```

For me to access a single key/values in the hash that is created [above] I have to use something like this.

$xml_file->{esxi01}{password}.

Oh yeah I forgot the actual XML file.

```
<Config>
  <esxi01>
    <password>password</password>
    <port>22</port>
    <user>root</user>
  </esxi01>
  <esxi02>
    <password>password</password>
    <port>22</port>
    <user>root</user>
  </esxi02>
  <Setup>FALSE</Setup>
</Config>
```

This is the simplest of the 3 or so I have.

Update:

The first part of the loop works with no problem, the problem happens when I try to use the second part of the loop.

Here is the way my code looks

```
my $xml = XML::Simple->new;

# Using the XML::Simple object, read guest_os.xml to a hash

my $xml_file = $xml->XMLin('config.xml',

                SearchPath => './config',

                SuppressEmpty => 1);

foreach my $server (keys %$xml_file) {
    foreach my $attribute (keys %{$xml_file->{$server}}) {
        print "$attribute\n";
    }
}
```

The output looks like this,

`Can't use string ("password") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at foreach_test line 21.`

I have tried using quotes in several places to fix the problem but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm sorry but this makes absolutely no sense. Can you please provide mode detailed example of what you mean by "because in order to access the hash it creates I have to use a function like $xml->{key} to get at the data. Well this makes a problem for me because I am not able to loop through keys in the hash that the module has setup"?

Comment: I think that you are confused - you are not accessing the data "through the XML::Simple module", in your code $xml_file is the data structure (i.e. the hash ref representing your XML data) returned from XML::Simple->XMLin. And to view the data structure that you get back from XML::Simple, then look at something like Data::Dumper (`print Dumper($xml_file)` will show you what you've got from parsing the XML)

Comment: and anyone using XML::Simple should definitely check out the various options (ForceArray, KeyAttr, etc), the defaults can cause confusion through inconsistency depending on the data - e.g. an arrayref can be present or not depending on whether the number of nodes is greater than one or not

Comment: Yeah I looked at the POD for XML::Simple and found several useful commands to help me out, As about the above comment, its complicated...at least in my head. But I have trouble conveying my problem in words since I am not really sure of all of names for functions and objects in perl. I am still hitting the books on the subject, getting better though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you need correctly - the question is very confusing. What you SEEM to be asking is:

- You have a complicated nested XML. E.g. `<t1><t2><t3>value</t3></t2></t1>`
- You seem to want to access contents of tag `<t3>` but without needing to go through the hash keys in a hash-of-hash-of... data structure that XML::Simple creates to represent the DOM. E.g. you don't want to do `$xml->{t1}->{t2}->{t3}`.

If that's the case, your problem is that you are using a DOM parser. A SAX parser (like `XML::Twig`) lets you execute events upon parsing specific tags, e.g. `t3` no matter where in the sructure that tag is.

---

If your problem is that you just don't know which tags exist (as keys in the hash),
you can do `keys %$xml` or `keys %{ $xml->{t1} }` to list them.

**UPDATE**

To loop using your example:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$xml) { # $key will be esxi01, etc...
    foreach my $attribute (keys %{ $xml->{$key} }) {
        "Key: $key; attribute: $attribute; value: $xml->{$key}->{$attribute}\n";
    }
    print "Port for $key: $xml->{$key}->{port}\n"; # Hardcoded
}
```

---

**UPDATE2**

The problem is in the `<Setup>FALSE</Setup>` XML tag. It has no subtags, so in the hash its value will be a SCALAR and not a hash.  To fix, you need to check that the inner element is, indeed, a hash:

```
foreach my $server (keys %$xml_file) {
    next if (ref ($xml_file->{$server}) ne ref({})); # Not a hash
    foreach my $attribute (keys %{$xml_file->{$server}}) {
        print "$attribute\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question...again with examples hopfully this helps somewhat.

Comment: @Solignis - added example, please tell me if it addresses your issue. In the future, if you problem is that your code gives you the error, post the code and the exact error

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the loop, or with my coding. I will update my question with the output and the code.

Comment: Actually I deleted my comment, it was just not clicking for me, I understand how your solution works now, it should work perfect for what I need. Sorry for all of the confusion. I blame the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the hash using `each` or `keys`:

```
while(($key, $value) = each(%$xml)) {
    print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
}

foreach my $key (keys %$xml) {
    print "key: $key, value: $xml->{$key}\n";
}
```